# Add values to bottom of DataFrame automatically with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm initializing a DataFrame:

```
columns = ['Thing','Time']
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

and then writing values to it like this:

```
for t in df.Thing.unique():
    df_temp = df[df['Thing'] == t]  #filtering the df
    df_new.loc[counter,'Thing'] = t #writing the filter value to df_new
    df_new.loc[counter,'Time'] = dftemp['delta'].sum(axis=0) #summing and adding that value to the df_new
    counter += 1 #increment the row index
```

Is there are better way to add new values to the dataframe each time without explicitly incrementing the row index with 'counter'?

Comment: Actually your problem is that you do a for loop. Dont. Use vector features of pandas

Comment: @Boud, I strive to :). In this case creating a groupby object or pivot table that captured the data that I wanted was elusive so I went for brute force. Any suggestions on that front would also be appreciated!

Comment: I'm a little confused at what's going on. Where is df and what types of values does it have? It sounds like you'll want to use the [append](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) method of DataFrame though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm interpreting this correctly, I think this can be done in one line:

```
newDf = df.groupby('Thing')['delta'].sum().reset_index()
```

By grouping by 'Thing', you have the various "t-filters" from your for-loop. We then apply a `sum()` to 'delta', but only within the various "t-filtered" groups. At this point, the dataframe has the various values of "t" as the indices, and the sums of the "t-filtered deltas" as a corresponding column. To get to your desired output, we then bump the "t's" into their own column via `reset_index()`.

Comment: That works! Thanks for helping me understand groupby better.